# Execute a command in shell and print out the summary (time + memory)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Sorry if the question is basic, is there options in shell to show how much time and how much memory (maximum memory occupied) the execution of a command has took?

Example: I want to call a binary file as follow: ./binary --option1 option1 --option2 option2

After the execution of this command I would like to know how much time and memory this command took.

Thanks

Comment: Measuring time is easy. But how would you define the memory usage of a program on a modern OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [time(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command, either as a separate executable or as a shell built-in, can be used to measure de the time used by a program, both in terms of wallclock time and CPU time.

But measuring the memory usage of a program, or even agreeing *how to define it*, is a bit different. Do you want the sum of its allocations? The maximum amount of memory allocated at a single moment? Are you interested in what the *code* does, or in the program behavior as a whole, where the memory allocator makes a difference? And how do you consider the memory used by shared objects? Or memory-mapped areas?

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) may help with some memory-related questions, but it is more of a development tool, rather than a day-to-day system administrator tool. More specifically the [Massif heap profiler](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) can be used to profile the memory usage of an application, but it does have a measurable  performance impact, especially with stack profiling enabled.

Comment: Thanks @thkala form the info, acutally I need to know only the maximum amout of memory allocation during the execution, just the maximum. My task is to provide for a processing server what is my exact need of memory, so I want to provide him with numbers about each process I call (execution time and maximum amount of memory allocated to the process). Thanks

Comment: @Rami: Have a look at the Massif profiler from Valgrind (see my update). For one-off estimates of memory usage it is quite usable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several files in `/proc` that might be simpler than using a profiler, assuming you know the PID of the process in which you're interested.

Of primary interest is `/proc/$PID/status` which lists ( among other things ) Virtual Memory Peak and Size ( VmPeak, VmSize respectively), and Resident "High Water Mark" and current sets ( VmHWM, VnRSS respectively )

I set up a simple C program to grab memory and then free it and then watched the file in `proc` corresponding to that program's PID, and it seemed to verify the manpage.

see `man proc` for a complete list of files that may interest you.

Here's the command line and program I used for the test:

Monitored with

```
PID="<program's pid>"
watch "cat /proc/$PID/status | grep ^Vm"
```

( compile with `gcc -o grabmem grabmem.c -std=c99` )

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INTNUM ( 1024 * 1024 )
#define PASSES 16
int main(){
    int* mems[16];
    int cur = 0;
    while( mems[cur] = (int*)calloc( sizeof( int ), INTNUM ) ){
        for( int i = 0; i < INTNUM; i++)
            mems[cur][i] = rand();
        printf("PID %i Pass %i: Grabbed another %lu of mem.\n",
            (int)getpid(),
            cur,
            sizeof(int) * INTNUM
        );
        sleep( 1 );
        cur++;
        if( cur >= 16 ){
            printf("Freeing memory...");
            for( cur = (PASSES - 1); cur >= 0; cur-- ){
                free(mems[cur] );
                mems[cur] = NULL;
            }
            cur = 0;
            printf("OK\n");
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't calloc() memory.\n");
    exit( -1 );
}
```